How to remove Namespaces in OIC SOAP Response mapper XSLT?
We are working on an integration in Oracle Integration Cloud (OIC) that returns a SOAP response. However, OIC is automatically adding namespaces to the SOAP response elements, which is causing parsing issues in BI Publisher.
Current Response:
<CreateReserveDocResponse xmlns="urn:createDocumentNumber">อว 660201.1.3.3/25551</CreateReserveDocResponse>

Expected Response:
<CreateReserveDocResponse>อว 660201.1.3.3/25551</CreateReserveDocResponse>

XSLT:
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="CreateReserveDocResponse" namespace="">
          <xsl:value-of select="$docNum"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

Is there a way to remove these namespaces at the element level in OIC? Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

In order to generically drop the namespaces from all elements, you can create a template that matches on any element and constructs an element using the local-name() of that element, then apply-templates to any attributes or child nodes in an identity transform.
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>


It would be better to raise the priority of the 2nd tempatle (anything above -0.5 will do) and not count on the processor recovering from the error.
